# Hibernate - Mapping only id not entire entity with foreign key constraint

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-mapping

Hi want to create a foreign key association/constraint but only map the primary key, not the entire entity. So what I want to achieve is something like this (which creates the correct db schema but fails on save):

```java
@Entity(name = "journal")
public class JournalEntry {
    @Id
    private UUID id;
  
    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = User.class, optional=false)
    @JoinColumn(name="id")
    private UUID userId;

    @Column
    private String text
}
```

In case the above is not possible, how can I manually specify that a foreign key constraint should be created?

This question did get asked quite a lot a few years ago but there was never a satisfactory answer and I thought maybe something changed in the last 8-12 years.

- [Hibernate foreign key mapping to value (not entity)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14326008/hibernate-foreign-key-mapping-to-value-not-entity)
- [Hibernate. Foreign key mapping by id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5487055/hibernate-foreign-key-mapping-by-id)
- [Hibernate - Foreign keys instead of Entities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6311776/hibernate-foreign-keys-instead-of-entities)
- [Hibernate: foreign key without entity class, only by id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32722941/hibernate-foreign-key-without-entity-class-only-by-id)
- [Hibernate - Foreign keys instead of Entities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6311776/hibernate-foreign-keys-instead-of-entities)

Comment: not sure if I understand well what you want, but @joinColumn tag has the possibility to define foreignkey as option:
@JoinColumn(name="id", foreignKey=@javax.persistence.ForeignKey(name="yourname", value = ConstraintMode.NO_CONSTRAINT)))

Comment: Instead of having the entire `User` class in the JournalEntry I only want the userId in it but still have the foreign key constraint defined so only existing userIds can be saved

Comment: maybe i see what you mean, instead to have the User you want just the UserId, Something like to have @ElementCollection for the list but you have a relation here with the whole table. I think you cannot have what you want without change the model. You can achieve something like that using the DTO instead or create a View to be handled by hibernate

Comment: I was hoping that is a common enough use case that it is possible. Is what I want to do considered an anti-pattern that it is not possible?

Comment: it's not an anti-pattern in my humble opinion. The fact is that, you are using some standard technologies that allow you a certain grade of customization, there are things that are not supported. But I want you to think how you can achieve this in a database (forgot about JPA and hibernate for a while)? maybe a view is what you need, but honestly at database level, with a foreign key in place, I don't see how you can achieve this otherwise